# PlayORM Cassandra Date Conversion Error

Tags: nosql, cassandra, playorm

I have PlayORM set up through maven.

My main class is basically copied from the example [here](http://buffalosw.com/wiki/Create-first-entity-using-Cassandra/.).

Every thing is set up properly and seems fine however I get some sort of date conversion error.

**Stacktrace below:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.toDate()Ljava/util/Date;
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.spi.UniqueKeyGenerator.<clinit>(UniqueKeyGenerator.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.z8spi.meta.ReflectionUtil.create(ReflectionUtil.java:11)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForField.processId(ScannerForField.java:94)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.processIdFieldWorks(ScannerForClass.java:235)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectFieldImpl(ScannerForClass.java:207)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.inspectField(ScannerForClass.java:194)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanFields(ScannerForClass.java:189)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.scanSingle(ScannerForClass.java:112)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.meta.scan.ScannerForClass.addClass(ScannerForClass.java:69)
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.scanClass(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:42)
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.discovered(MyClassAnnotationDiscoveryListener.java:34)
at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discoverAndIntimateForClassAnnotations(Discoverer.java:197)
at com.impetus.annovention.Discoverer.discover(Discoverer.java:155)
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.rescan(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:80)
at com.alvazan.orm.layer0.base.BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.setup(BaseEntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:131)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstanceImpl(BootstrapImpl.java:64)
at com.alvazan.orm.impl.bindings.BootstrapImpl.createInstance(BootstrapImpl.java:35)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:57)
at com.alvazan.orm.api.base.Bootstrap.create(Bootstrap.java:52)
at com.sample.cass.store.Example.main(Example.java:22)
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError always means there is a jar incompatible.  ie. one client jar is compiled with one jar like joda-time 2.0 but you are using another jar which does not have that method instead of the one it was compiled with.  To be safe, use gradle and make sure you check which projects bring in which jars and try to use the lateste jars(though sometimes libraries remove methods too unfortunately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please copy-paste your code and complete error log here. From the log you have pasted, it seems that either:

There is some different version of JodaTime's jar in your classpath which doesn't have this method.
Or
The stacktrace you copied is not complete and problem is similar to [Can PlayORM take advantage of sequential data layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578699/can-playorm-take-advantage-of-sequential-data-layout/15680972#15680972) as it is throwing error at (Line 32 of UniqueKeyGenerator.java)

Comment: I did have version 1.6.2 of joda time in my classpath, although it is not currently being used by any models or any part of the code directly so it could be removed. What version is supported?

The main code is basically what is here: http://buffalosw.com/wiki/Create-first-entity-using-Cassandra/

Comment: Try removing that. Playorm supports joda-time-2.0

Comment: Hi, I am having similar issue, except exception is thrown in UniqueKeyGenerator on line 47.
The version of Joda in the build path is 2.0

Comment: Can you paste the complete stacktrace..As Dean mentioned that it always come if there is a jar incompatible. Do check in your code if you have transitive dependencies on JodaTime from some other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
The reason is "jruby-complete-1.6.5" library ships with "joda time 1.6.2".